# Menu added not showing

Tags: 7, routes

I have added a menu item in main-menu using following code

```
$item = array(
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
    'link_path' => 'my-profile',
    'link_title' => 'Services',
    'module' => 'menu',
    'weight' => 0,
);
menu_link_save($item);
menu_cache_clear_all();
```

this code is placed in lcp_theme function, lcp is custom module and is working properly except this added menu item.
I cant see this menu at top of the site in main menu.

As per the documentation I can use this function anywhere in module.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying is to add a menu item in main menu, you can implement `hook_menu`, code something as below.

```
function my_module_name_menu() {
  $items['test'] = array(
    'title'           => 'Tes Page',
    'description'     => t('Test'),
    'menu_name'       => 'main-menu',
    'weight'          => 8,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page callback'   => '_my_module_name_test_page',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}

function _my_module_name_test_page() {
  return "hi";
}
```

Key is to have `'menu_name' => 'main-menu',` in menu item declaration.